# Looking for an example for a simplegeo API call in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

After authenticating with simplegeo, I am simply trying to perform this:

```
SimpleGeo::Client.get_context(37.772445,-122.405913)
```

Turn the result into `@variable` and display the `@variable` on my "view" page.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you try to do that?

Comment: It dumps the raw response into the webpage.  Unfortunately it does not parse the JSON data so I am trying to clean it up.

Comment: what exactly is your problem? The response from `simplegeo` doesn't parse by `JSON.parse`?

Comment: I am not exactly sure how to incorporate JSON.parse into my controller file to interact with SimpleGeo::Client.get_context(coordinates, coordinates).  Then not sure how to display the parsed JSON result into my view file.

Comment: I'm working on an example for this. You basically just need to parse the object and display properties. Pseudo-code:

@response = SimpleGeo::Client.get_context(37.772445,-122.405913)

Comment: Possible to check out the example when it's ready?  Many thanks!

Comment: Any ideas how to pull a specific result from within the JSON response? and display that rather than the entire response?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a gem right now called SimpleGeo-Rails. It should make the whole process of working with the SimpleGeo Places a lot more rails-like. Just add the following to your Gemfile and then [checkout the readme](https://github.com/mgadda/simplegeo-rails).

```
gem 'simplegeo-rails', :git => 'https://github.com/mgadda/simplegeo-rails.git'
```